# Why is Amazon Web Services charging me for their SSD usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing, solid-state-drive

I got a bill form Amazon charging me $1.20. for `$0.12 per GB-month of General Purpose (SSD) provisioned storage - US West (Northern California)`? They said I used 10.000 GB last month but I haven't done a single thing with AWS. How is this happening and how to I stop this from happening again?

Comment: do you have snapshots of EC2 instances or databases? Any other usage? This is hard to answer without more information.

Comment: Perhaps this is best answered by contacting AWS support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your **Elastic Block Storage - Volume** inside [EC2 Web Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Volumes:sort=desc:createTime)? Maybe there is something left inside there. It's your SSD volume.

Comment: Yeah I do, I have 5 volumes that are in-use. The only option available is to detach them but every time I do so it gives me an error and won't let m do so.

Comment: Try to look into http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html. If you can't detach and force detach, ask AWS support for help. But, also try to terminate related EC2 instances.